# Building DOM document from xml string gives me a null document

Tags: java, xml, string, dom

I'm trying to use the DOM library to parse a string in xml format. For some reason my document contains nulls and I run into issues trying to parse it. The string variable 'response' is not null and I am able to see the string when in debug mode.

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("BatchFile");;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            NodeList batchItem = element.getChildNodes();
            String uri = batchItem.item(0).getNodeValue();
            String id = batchItem.item(1).getNodeValue();
            String fqName = batchItem.item(2).getNodeValue();
          }
```

Highlighting over the line `Document doc = builder.parse(is);` after it has run shows the result of `[#document: null]`.

Edit: I've managed to not got an empty doc now but the string values are still null (at end of code). How would I get the value of something like this

```
        <GetBatchFilesResult>
            <BatchFile>
                <Uri>uri</Uri>
                <ID>id</ID>
                <FQName>file.zip</FQName>
            </BatchFile>

        </GetBatchFilesResult>
```

Comment: This is just the `Document.toString` method - doesn't mean anything useful. What are the problems exactly?

Comment: Wildcards do not function in `getElementsByTagName("*");`. Check every `node.items(i) instanceof Element`, and recurse.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything at all in the document. doc.getChildNodes doesn't show any nodes at all when I know there are nodes in the xml string.

Comment: doc.getDocumentElement()? Did you check `response`?

Comment: .NodeName() does return a value but I .NodeValue() is returning a null or error.

Comment: @zms6445 how did you manage to not get an empty doc? I am having the same problem i.e getting a `[#document: null]`. Even though I see the response string is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use getTextContent(). getNodeValue will return null for elements. Besides, you'd better use getElementsByTagName, since white spaces are also treated as one of the child nodes.

```
Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
String uri = element.getElementsByTagName("Uri").item(0).getTextContent();
String id =  element.getElementsByTagName("ID").item(0).getTextContent();
String fqName =  element.getElementsByTagName("FQName").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Check [Node API document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) to see what type of nodes will return null for getNodeValue.

Comment: Thanks. This simplified my answer very well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Seems stupid that you have to do it this way to get a value from a node.

```
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

        NodeList batchItem = element.getChildNodes();
        Element uri = (Element) batchItem.item(0);
        Element id = (Element) batchItem.item(1);
        Element fqName = (Element) batchItem.item(2);
        NodeList test = uri.getChildNodes();
        NodeList test1 = id.getChildNodes();
        NodeList test2 = fqName.getChildNodes();

        String strURI= test.item(0).getNodeValue();
        String strID= test1.item(0).getNodeValue();
        String strFQName= test2.item(0).getNodeValue();
```